# What are the ridges seen on sprockets and chainrings for?

Tags: cassette, drivetrain, sprocket, hyperglide

I've always wondered what these ridges below the teeth on sprockets are for. Can anyone enlighten me?

[image: mysterious sprocket ridges]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They are there to help [facilitate shifting](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/gloss_ra-e.html). Basically, the ramps you see help when going from a smaller to larger sprocket by catching the side plates of the chain to help the chain be pulled up onto the larger cog.

Another place where you will see atypical teeth is in the front; some are shorter/different shaped than others to help shifting as well. Sometimes you see pins as well.

Comment: Yes, and a chain designed for indexed shifting will have pins that project out slightly, to catch the ramps on the sides of the cogs when the chain is shifted against them.

Comment: (These ramps and the extended pins are what make "indexed shifting" possible.  Before them it was necessary to have "friction shifting", with no detents, since the cyclist needed to "overshift" slightly to cause the shift, then adjust back a little once shifted.)

Comment: Fantastic, thanks chaps. Years of wondering ended by a rapid answer. It seems so obvious now.

Comment: I believe Shimano invented the idea, which they called "[Hyperglide](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/gloss_ho-z.html#hyperglide)" for the rear and "Superglide" for the front.  According to Sheldon Brown, the ramps allow the new cog to engage before the old cog has completely disengaged, which allows for much smoother and quieter shifts.  I remember the days of friction shifters and plain cogs, when shifts took longer, you couldn't apply power while shifting (I still try not to), and chattering noise was inevitable.  The new system with indexed shifting and ramped cog teeth is much nicer.

Comment: @rclocher3 - Yeah, Hyperglide (and indexed shifting in general) is the single most significant advance in bike design in the past 40 years.

Comment: What I find amazing is that this needed no new technology whatsoever. Somebody in a workshop sat down with a file and a grinder  and experimented. Out came a crooked tooth here and a groove there, with significantly easier shifting. That could have been done at any point in time during the 20th century. It's possible but I think not necessary that CAD/CAM/rapid prototyping  helped; and the need was more pressing with indexed shifting. But still.